# Causing PostBack with page refresh in vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a VB project with a Site.Master page and several other .aspx pages.  I have an asp:DropDownList on Site.Master.  When the user changes the dropdown selection, I want whichever .aspx page is shown to refresh - *with* PostBack, as though the user changed a setting on the .aspx page and caused a PostBack to that page.

Currently, I have a full page refresh with

```
Protected Sub ddlPlant_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ddlPlant.SelectedIndexChanged
    Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString(), True)
End Sub
```

The problem: this refreshes everything, which resets the dropdownlist, clears any Session data, and clears any user-input data that the .aspx page would normally save during a postback.

How do I cause the .aspx page and the Site.Master page to do a normal postback, instead of a full refresh?

Comment: Just remove the code from the ddlPlant_SelectedIndexChanged method, that should perform a standard postback

Answer (score 1):

Upon the selection of the DropDownList changing, the Page's Load Event Handler (Page_Load) should be getting called with the Page's PostBack Property equaling True before ddlPlant_SelectedIndexChanged is called.  If you must call it again after that Method finishes, just call your Event Handler for the Page Load event:

```
Protected Sub ddlPlant_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ddlPlant.SelectedIndexChanged
    Page_Load(Nothing, Nothing)
End Sub
```

Comment: This does cause my Site.Master's Page_Load function to run again, thank you.  Not a solution to my specific problem, but definitely good to know for the future.

Answer (score 0):

As Don Jayamanne said above - the solution was to remove the Response.Redirect line from my code, and it would cause a normal PostBack.  Thanks!